# Cómo integrar thymeleaf con jwt en una aplicación monolítica?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jwt, thymeleaf

Estoy intentando realizar una sitio web en el que uso jwt para la seguridad de la aplicación, para ello me estoy guiando por este post https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/spring-security-jwt-authentication-postgresql-restapis-springboot-spring-mvc-spring-jpa

El problema es que quiero usarlo pero no como un servicio aparte sino dentro de la misma aplicación usando thymeleaf(un sitio web monolítico) que no dependa de otro servidor.

Me pueden dar alguna sugerencia? será esto posible o existen otros métodos mejores de seguridad para una aplicación monolítica?

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede, solo añade tu funcion de authenticacion por JWT a tus reglas de negocio como un servicio o controlador dentro de tu aplicacion, es lo que a mi se me ocurre.
Si buscas otros metodos de seguridad porque no intentas con [Spring Security](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-example/) ya que tiene una fuerte compatibilidad con Thymeleaf, en lo personal, si cambiaria el JWT ya que es mas como para authenticacion para API REST que para una aplicacion web